# Loading less.min.js cdn results in blank page

Tags: javascript, html, less

I'm trying to implement .less on my page, by adding the tag:

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>`

I've tried this on different pages(so not content related), tried it on the top of the page and the bottom of the page, also had the oppertunity to try it on both mac and windows, but I always get a blank page, when I remove it, it's fine again, but I would like to start using it, what am I doing wrong?

CDN source: http://lesscss.org

Comment: What kind of page are you adding it to? Because the scheme is missing from the URL, if you're including this script in a local html file then the scheme will be `file://`, so the browser will request `file:///cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js` - Try prefixing the URL with `http:` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I'm adding this to a php file outside the <?php ?> tags. I noticed the // at the beginning of the URL, but this is how it is supplied by lesscss.org, and I've tried to add http: or https: in front of it, with the same result.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your HTML/PHP with the script tag included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `async` option being set to `false` which makes the script add `display: none` to the `<body>` tag styling while the LESS files are being parsed.

Without any LESS files to parse on your page, the script never finishes and therefore never removes the `display: none`. To resolve the issue, either add some links to your LESS files to the page, or set the `async` option to `true` before the script is loaded like so:

```
    <script>
      less = {
        async: true
      };
    </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy, this worked like a charm. I couldn't find any documentation on the issue but this was spot on!

Comment: I couldn't find much in the docs about it either, but I set up a fiddle and noticed it was adding display none to the body, so I searched for "display" in the source code and found out it was doing that when the `async` option is set to false. I think the fact it doesn't remove the display none when there are no LESS files in the source is a bug.

Comment: Yeah, at least a loading icon or feedback telling you what's wrong would be nice indeed. Many thanks for your quick answer, you made my day.